# Filtrations of modular forms on $\Gamma_0(N)$ using results on $\Gamma_1(N)$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, modular-forms

In Jochnowitz's paper "Congruences between Systems of Eigenvalues of Modular Forms," she appeals to Katz's paper "A result on  Modular Forms in Characteristic p" to prove the equality of mod $p$ filtrations $w(f^p) = p w(f)$ (Fact 1.7 in the Jochnowitz). Here, for $f$ a modular form mod $p$, $w(f)$ denotes the smallest weight $k$ for which $f$ lifts to a modular form with $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients in $M_k(\Gamma_0(N))$.

However, Jochnowitz is working with modular forms on $\Gamma_0(N)$, and Katz with modular forms on $\Gamma_1(N)$. Moreover, the fact is not true for $p = 2,3$, a hypothesis that Jochnowitz assumes, but does not explicitly mention in the proof. Why is it that Katz's $\Gamma_1(N)$ results can be readily extended to $\Gamma_0(N)$ for $p \ge 5$? I suspect that the $p \ge 5$ dependence has something to do with the Hasse invariant in characteristic $p$ lifting to a characteristic $0$ modular form, but I have not yet figured out the exact relationship.

So far, I have tried showing that if $f$ is a modular form with $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients on $\Gamma_1(N)$ congruent mod $p$ to a modular form on $\Gamma_0(N)$, then $f$ is itself on $\Gamma_0(N)$. However, this appears not to be true.